# Mac OS X - Terminal folder/file name spacing fix?

Tags: macos, terminal

I have been using Ubuntu for a while, and now trying to use OS X's terminal. However, the folder/name spacing in OS X's terminal really bothers the heck out of me because it's uneven, please see:

[image]

You can tell that the spacing in line 2 and 5 and line 8 are different and uneven.

Does any guru know of a fix for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use use ls -alF or ls -1.

I think OS-X ls will align file names depending on their length to be most compact.